# Form validation error in ReactJS not firing first time

Tags: reactjs

My intention was to have a switch, and to validate the appropriate element using an onChange event.  It looks like the onChange is sending the previous value of the input field, therefore my validateSearch function is not picking up an error straight away.

Here is an example.  You will see that when the age is changed below 18, the onClick event lags behind.  How can I prevent this?
https://codesandbox.io/s/vpgzk

Comment: I can sort this out for you. Give me a moment

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[Working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-tdd-7t6oh?file=/src/App.js:0-779)

After you've read this code you may have some more questions. Feel free to ask them.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const adultAge = 18
const childWarning = 'Under 18'
const emptyStr = ''

function App() {
  const [readAge, writeAge] = useState("18");
  const [readErrors, writeErrors] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    if (readAge < adultAge) writeErrors({age: childWarning})
    else writeErrors({age: emptyStr})
  }, [readAge])

  const tooYoung = readErrors.age !== emptyStr

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <input
          type="number"
          value={readAge}
          onChange={(e) => writeAge(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button type="submit" disabled={tooYoung}>Submit</button>
      </form>
      {tooYoung && <p style={{color: 'red'}}>You are not old enough</p>}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  Could you explain why my version was always one step behind?  Does it have something to do with the fact that your solution has a separate constant (tooYoung) to track it?  I don't fully understand why going 18 > 17 >18 or 18 > 17 > 16 causes console.log to fire.

Comment: Run your code through a debugger in VSCode. The answer will become clear. [Tutorial here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PJeNReqyH88)

Comment: Can you please explain your solution @AlexMckay? It is not helpful unless there is an explanation